# Execute PyAutoGUI code on second MacBook Pro desktop

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have the following code, which matches a screenshot of the "Tech" header/button from the Wall Street Journal's front page, and then clicks on it -

```
import pyautogui as pya
import time

# timing start
start = time.time()

# center of screen
pya.moveTo(840, 525, 1)

# navigate to "Tech" button
p = pya.locateOnScreen('wsj-tech.png', confidence = 0.8, grayscale=False)
print(p)
x, y = pya.center(p)
x, y = x/2, y/2
d = pya.moveTo(x, y, 1)
pya.doubleClick(d)

# end timer
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

To execute the code, I have to set the IDE (spyder) above (below also works) the browser:

[image]

Is there any way I can leave the browser on another desktop? E.g. execute the script in spyder (on "Desktop 2"), and then swipe over to "Desktop 1" to see the autoclicker work on the WSJ page?

FYI the computer is **not** connected to any external desktops.

[image]

Comment: Can you add more clarity on what you are looking to Achieve? And if you mean workspace on the same computer by referring to desktop 1 and 2. Then you will not be able to see what's happening on the other workspace. Work spaces are created to provide a distraction free environment. With that said, this is less of a coding challenge.

Comment: Simple trying to execute the code in my IDE (desktop 2), and have it click on the Tech banner on desktop 1. Don't really have to see or need to see it happening. E.g., I pull up the WSJ on one screen, swipe over to the code, execute, and then swipe back to see that it clicked on the Tech banner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question! Unfortunately, it is ***not possible*** to do what you're asking with `pyautogui`. This is because `pyautogui` can only work on foreground objects/windows and not minimized objects/windows in the background or in another workspace. It is a noted [feature request](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/pull/430), who knows if or when it might get implemented.

**Possible Solutions:**

- If you don't need the GUI, just use the `python` library [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/py) to find the WSJ banner and click on it with a *headless* chrome browser instance (browser will be hidden)
- Have your code & browser run in a *virtual machine*, so it can then execute without having to be in the foreground
- Try `python` library [atomacos](https://github.com/daveenguyen/atomacos) which provides automation of `macOS` GUI applications
- Use a `macOS` automation tool like [Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org/) which allows you to move windows, talk to other applications, etc

Comment: Thanks! Was definitely hoping to avoid Selenium, but I see what you mean. Will take your suggestions into account!